# Python web crawler doesn't crawl all pages

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a web crawler that crawls a set number of pages, but it only crawls the first page, and prints it as many times as the amount of pages i want to crawl.

```
def web_spider (max_pages):
page = 1
while page <= max_pages:
    url = 'http://www.forbes.com/global2000/list/#page:' + str(page) + '_sort:0_direction:asc_search:_filter:All%20industries_' \
                                                                       'filter:All%20countries_filter:All%20states'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        if link.parent.name == 'td':
            href = link.get('href')
            x = href[11:len(href)-1]
            company_list.append(x)
    page += 1
print(page)
return company_list
```

Edit: Did it another way.

Comment: It seems you have defined `company_list` _outside_ of your function, i.e. as a global variable. This way, the results will accumulate, i.e. if you call that function multiple times, the result list will hold the results of each of those calls.

Comment: tried to make it a local variabel, still doesn't work

Comment: Well, when I put that URL with different values for `page` in my browser, I always end up at the same page, showing the same list of companies. Seems like the problem is in the URL. EDIT: No, I actually get different results, but only when I open the URL in a new tab, not when I edit the current URL and reload... also, it always shows page 1 first, and then, after about a second, switches the page. Probably some weird cookies thing.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want the dataset, you can use your browsers developer tools to find what network resources are used by clicking on Record network traffic and refresh the page to see how the table is populated. In this case I found the following URL:

https://www.forbes.com/forbesapi/org/global2000/2020/position/true.json?limit=2000

Does that help you?